# Notation in periodic sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

I am reading a paper but I am stuck on some notation I haven't seen before. I tried searching online but I haven't found anything. The notation in question is this:

$$u_i = \{u^{(1)}_i\}$$

Here is an excerpt from the paper for context:

> The field $Z_2$ consists of two elements: 0 and 1. The multiplication rules are the usual ones. The addition rules are: 0 + 0 = 0, 0 + 1 = 1, 1 + 0 = 1, 1 + 1 = 0.
>
> Consider the m-th order linear difference equation
> $$Lu_i=0 \tag{2.1} $$
> where the difference operator
> $$Lu_i \equiv u_{i+m}+a_1u_{i+m-1}+...+a_{m-1}u_{i+1}+u_i \tag{2.2} $$
> all $u_i$ and $a_i$ belong to $Z_2$.
>
> Each solution of equation (2.1)  will be assumed to be given for all $-\infty<i<\infty$. They are uniquely determined by the initial values $(u_0, u_1, ..., u_{m-1})$. If all the initial values are zeros, we obtain the trivial solution $\{u_i\}=0$. The number of different solutions of equation (2.1), including the trivila one, is equal to $2^m$.
>
> All solutions of equation (2.1) are periodic. Let us fix the solution $u_i = \{u^{(1)}_i\}$. Obviously, all solutions of the form $u_i = \{u^{(1)}_{i+a}\}$ have the same period (which will be always understood to be the smallest positive period) and form one cycle.

The first occurrence of something similar to this notation is $\{u_i\}=0$. I assume this is an alternative to $\langle u_i \rangle$ and means "every element in the sequence". I can't, however, figure out how this applies to the case of $u_i = \{u^{(1)}_i\}$.

Note: I am taking the exerpt from: *On the distribution of points in a cube and the approximate evaluation of integrals* by I. Sobol'.

Comment: I can only guess that $u_i=\{u_{i+a}^{(1)}\}$ means: "the original sequence, shifted by $a$". But how this notation is supposed to express that, is beyond me